# How to use python to convert a string to a list?

Tags: python, string, list

As in the title, I want to convert the string `'abc'` to `['abc']`.

My code is as follows. Why is the `codes` obtained as `None`?

How can I write it correctly?

```
code = 'abc'
codes = []
if code != '':
    codes = codes.append(code)
```

Comment: The append method modifies the list in place and returns `None`. Replace the last line with `codes.append(code)`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `codes = [code]`?

Comment: Thanks, using `codes.append(code)` or `[code] `is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.append` operates in-place. It doesn't return a result (thus, it returns `None`. You're assigning this to `codes`, hence you end up with `codes = None`.

You just need to call `append`:

```
code = 'abc'
codes = []
if code != '':
    codes.append(code)
```

better yet, use a list literal:

```
code = 'abc'
codes = [code] if code else []
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a simple mistake. Instead of writing `codes = codes.append(code)` you need only `codes.append(code)`.